# Problem with Identity UserManager error on password hashing

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, password-hash, usermanager

when I use this code:

```
   var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();
                string hashedPassword = passwordHasher.HashPassword(pp.Password);

                User newUser = new User()    
                {
                    UserName = pp.NationalCode,
                    Pcode = pp.Pcode,
                    PasswordHash = hashedPassword,
                };

                var result = _UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser).Result;
```

the result will be succeeded, but if I use below code

```
                User newUser = new User()    
                {
                    UserName = pp.NationalCode,
                    Pcode = pp.Pcode,
                   
                };

                var result = _UserManager.CreateAsync(newUser,pp.Pasword).Result;
```

Result will be false.

On the other hand, because the password that is not systematically generated by Identity Hash, I can not use it in the login of users because (probably and certainly) the algorithms are different.

my codes in Login are :

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = _UserManager.FindByNameAsync(lc.UserName).Result;
            _SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
            if (user != null)
            {
                var result =await _SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user,lc.Password, lc.IsPersistent, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    TempData["LoggedUserCode"] = user.Pcode;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid User or Password");

        }
```

Comment: What the reason that you want to use your own password hasher?

Comment: You probably need to implement your own `IPasswordValidator`

Comment: I don't need to do Hashing password manually. Just I did it for testing to ensure if the problem issues from password hash or another item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with the help of an expert friend. In customizing the user table, I had mistakenly added a password field, which I removed it and the problem of adding new user solved.
Also, the post action was defined as async, I removed async and the login problem solved.